# pyenv local - can't set a Python version by its number despite the fact that it's installed

Tags: python, pyenv

Any suggestions on how you set the version of Python for pyenv?

E.g.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13) 
$ pyenv local
pyenv: no local version configured for this directory
$ pyenv local 3.6.0
pyenv: version `3.6.0' not installed
$ pyenv local v3.6.0:41df79263a11
pyenv: version `v3.6.0' not installed
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to set up an virtual env first. For example, you can create a env called `pyenv360` by

```
$ pyenv virtualenv 3.6.0 pyenv360
```

And set it as your default python for your folder `my-folder` by

```
$ cd my-folder
$ pyenv local pyenv360
```

By doing this, whenever you enter this folder, it'll start using `pyenv360` which references `python 3.6.0` in this case.

You can check if it's working by:

```
$ pyenv local
```

which should show `pyenv360`.

Comment: You have to install pyenv-virtualenv for this answer to work. You just go to their gh page and clone their repo into your pyenv root (instructions on that gh page): https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv

Comment: This would produce the same error in the OP's case. See my answer why.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>(Assuming you installed `pyenv` according to the official instructions.)</sub>

`pyenv` recognizes two kinds of Python installations:

- `system` -- Python executables from `PATH`, regardless of their versions
- numbered versions -- installed with `pyenv install` under `$PYENV_ROOT/versions`

`pyenv` considers the former installations outside its control, so its commands don't take their versions into account when looking for a specific version.

---

To find out which installation, from `pyenv`'s POV, your `python3` refers to, check

- `pyenv versions`

  - whether the selected Python 3 version is "system"; or
- `which python3` (and `pyenv which python3` if the former points into `<pyenv root>/shims/`)

  - whether the result points to outside `$PYENV_ROOT`

If your 3.6.0 installation is indeed outside of `pyenv`'s control, you need to select it with `pyenv local system` and make sure on your own that your `PATH` is arranged to point to it.

- More specifically, that your `PATH` first points to `<pyenv_root>/shims` and then to the correct `python3`

  - You can use `which -a python3` to quickly check that

Answer (score 3):

**Overview**

'pyenv' has the feature to set the 'local' and the 'global' version,

where 'local' is the version that we set for a particular directory and it automatically gets activated if you are in that directory or any of its subdirectory(if another 'local' is not set for that subdirectory) in a hierarchical fashion.

whereas 'global' is the version that we set for all over the system and it is available to any directory(if the local is not set for that directory otherwise the local version would be available in that directory)

**How to set 'global' and 'local'**

now to set 'global' or the 'local' version of the python, that python version should be installed in your system, be it by the 'os' you used or by the 'pyenv'. *And there is no need of virtual environment creation at all.*

*To Install any version via 'pyenv'*

see the output of
`pyenv install --list`
choose one of the name(eg. 3.6.0) and use command
`pyenv install <version-name>`

Note that the version of python that is installed by the os is called 'system' by the 'pyenv' and the versions that are installed by the 'pyenv' would be represented by the version number of that python version.
to see all the versions installed by the pyenv use `pyenv versions`

Now coming to the question of how to set the global version and the local version, use

`pyenv global <version-name-as used-by-pyenv>` (the version has to be installed)
to set the global version

and for setting the local python,
first, move to the directory in which you want to set the local version,
and then

`pyenv local <version-name-as used-by-pyenv>`

**Issue that I faced in ubuntu 20.04, and in Linux mint 20**

Now sometimes the 'system' python is not accessible due to its unreachability by 'pyenv' and the reason is well explained by @ivan_pozdeev, but I would like to address the wired issue that I face in ubuntu 20.04 and Linux mint 20(as it's based on ubuntu 20.04).

Here I am not able to access the system python, even though the system python binaries are well in the path of pyenv.

the error was
`pyenv: system version not found in PATH`

reason: the 'system' is not found by the pyenv, because pyenv was looking for binaries with name 'python' and not 'python3' in the path(which is '/usr/bin'), and in ubuntu 20.04 the python binaries are addressed with name 'python3', and not with 'python'

solution: the solution is to create the symlink for 'python3' named as 'python' in '/usr/bin' and the command used is
`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`